# Example of Something That's Not A Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

Two examples of non-manifolds that I know are the cross and the cone. Also the sphere with a hair isn't a topological manifold. But what's an example of a topological space $X$ such that $X$ is not a manifold and $X\setminus\{p_1,\ldots p_n\}$ is not a manifold for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p_i\in X$?

Comment: The Cantor set.

Comment: A manifold is a set with a certain structure, so every set is automatically not a manifold without that structure. Do you mean to ask for topological spaces that aren't manifolds, or subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that aren't manifolds, etc.?

Comment: Yes, meant topological space.

Comment: If you do not count manifolds with boundary as topological manifolds, the closure of any nonempty, non-dense open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n \geq 2}$.

Comment: Union of a disk and a line.

Comment: Or any infinite set with the indiscrete topology, or any set with any topology which is not Hausdorff, et cetera.

Comment: If you come up with a space that doesn't have one of the local properties of $\mathbb{R}$, it cannot ever be considered a manifold. For example, a space that is not locally compact around any point (such as $\mathbb{Q}$), a space that's not locally path-connected, a space that's not Hausdorff, etc.

Comment: Take any Euclidian space, $E^n$ and an open proper subset, $S$ (such as any open ball) and form the quotient space $E^n/S$. Points on the boundary of the open ball will cluster around the point that is is obtained by quotienting by $S$.

Comment: I was just thinking of something that's not locally Euclidean, even if you remove countably many points. I wasn't thinking about the Hausdorff or second countable conditions.

Comment: Then, again:  the Cantor set is your man.

Comment: Just put together pieces of different dimensions, sphere with a hair won't be a manifold even if you remove connecting point since pieces aren't locally homeomorphic to the same $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you don't like that just attach hairs at countably many points or even at a continuum of points.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense, thank you everyone for your answers! Should have waited a few more minutes before asking!

Comment: @Adam Dammit,that's what I was gonna say! I'm too slow......lol

Comment: What if you took a smooth ball in 3-space, cut out a hole, and fuzzed up that hole, like cutting an infinite number of "nicks" in it that obstruct the flats from being stitched together?

You could also imagine a "foam" where there are an infinite number of "bubbles" obstructing the flats, wherever you want to stitch two of them together.

(i.e., think of a loaf of bread, is it a manifold? What about the crannies? What if there was always a "cranny" keeping it from being smooth?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to take this off the unanswered list, here are some of the answers from the comments:
Feel free to add to this list, or edit it in any way that makes sense.

$\bullet$ The cantor set : **Adam Hughes**

$\bullet$ If manifolds with boundary are not no be considered manifolds: the closure of any non-empty , non-dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n\geq 2}$ :**user7530**

$\bullet$ Union of a disk and a line: **900 sit-ups a day** (that is impressive)
          (this one would depend one how we are unionizing a disk and a line, for instance, the disjoint union would still be a manifold)

$\bullet$ Or any infinite set with the indiscrete topology, or any set with any topology which is not Hausdorff, et cetera.: **Adam Hughes**

$\bullet$ A subclass of the last is, Take any Euclidian space, En and an open proper subset, S (such as any open ball) and form the quotient space En/S. Points on the boundary of the open ball will cluster around the point that is is obtained by quotienting by S.: **Baby Dragon**

$\bullet$ A space that is not locally compact around any point (such as ℚ), a space that's not locally path-connected, a space that's not Hausdorff, etc. : **dorebell**

$\bullet$ Just put together pieces of different dimensions, sphere with a hair won't be a manifold even if you remove connecting point since pieces aren't locally homeomorphic to the same ℝn. If you don't like that just attach hairs at countably many points or even at a continuum of points.: **Conifold**

And you can probably find many more examples in the book *Couterexamples in Topology*.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY, YOU SHOULD LOOK FOR FURTHER EXAMPLES IN STEEN AND SEEBACH JR'S CLASSIC BOOK! You can also look in Spivak's differential geometry book-there are several counterexamples in the exercises of volume 1.

Comment: I just discovered there's also a website for counterexamples in topology (not the book so much as literal counterexamples): https://topology.pi-base.org/